# Dúvida com operações de laço

Tags: r, loop

Tenho este `df`:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 6, expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100), simplify = TRUE
  ), 
  y = as.factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE))
)
```

Eu gostaria de saber a causa de as duas primeiras funções funcionarem e a terceira e a quarta não. Escolhi a função `pairwise.t.test` de forma arbitrária para exemplificar.

Pra mim, todas seriam equivalentes:

**1)**

```
vars <- names(df_1)[c(1:6)]

for (i in vars) {
  print(
    pairwise.t.test(x = df_1[, i], df_1$y, p.adj = 'bonferroni')
  )
}
```

Funciona.

**2)**

```
for (i in names(df_1)[c(1:6)]) {
  print(
    pairwise.t.test(x = df_1[, i], df_1$y, p.adj = 'bonferroni')
  )
}
```

Também funciona.

O loop a seguir, que pra mim é equivalente aos anteriores, não é executado:

**3)**

```
for (i in df_1) {
  print(
    pairwise.t.test(x = names(i)[c(1:6)], i$y, p.adj = 'bonferroni')
  )
}
```

**4)**

Por fim, sabe-se que:

```
df_1[1]
```

equivale a

```
df_1[, 1]
```

e

```
df_1[,1]
```

Todas retornam a primeira coluna do `df`. Mas, se eu retiro a vírgula (`,` ) de `df_1[, i]` ou se retiro o espaço entre `,` e `i` (`[,i]`) na função **1)** e **2)** o loop não funciona e "funciona errado", respectivamente:

**sem a vírgula**

```
for (i in vars) {
  print(
    pairwise.t.test(x = df_1[i], df_1$y, p.adj = 'bonferroni')
  )
}
```

> Error in tapply(x, g, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
>     arguments must have same length

**sem o espaço**

```
for (i in vars) {
  print(
    pairwise.t.test(x = df_1[,i], df_1$y, p.adj = 'bonferroni')
  )
}

# Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

# data:  df_1[, i] and df_1$y 

#   1 2
# 2 1 -
# 3 1 1

# P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

- Quais os motivos de **3)** e **4)** não funcionarem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou tratar do loop 1 e 2 porque eles funcionam e também porque eles são a mesma coisa com a diferença que uma usa a variável `vars` e a outra a calcula *on the fly* (no comando do loop).

Vou comparar os loops 3 e 4 com o 1. Vou mudar de 6 colunas para duas para que a resposta fique menos prolixa. Outra mudança que vou fazer é trocar o "cálculo complexo" no corpo do loop por um `print(i)` para vermos o que esta acontecendo dentro do loop.

## Dados usados

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 2, expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100), simplify = TRUE
  ), 
  y = as.factor(sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE))
)
vars <- names(df_1)[c(1:2)]
```

## Loop 1

```
for (i in vars) print(i)
#> [1] "x.1"
#> [1] "x.2"
```

O que está acontecendo no loop 1 é que o nome da variável está sendo passado para a função `` `[`() ``, que sabe lidar com `texto` e extrai a variável de mesmo nome.

## Loop 3

Já no loop 3 o que ocorre é que o `i` passa a representar os dados mesmos do `data.frame`.

```
for (i in df_1) print(i)
#> [1] 30.26077 82.59508 71.04249 99.67011 36.02907 20.69992 31.05353 60.14356 40.53777 32.07807 23.52082 60.28327
#> [13] 49.96783 96.53946 94.50641 72.01676 94.42794 20.56521 20.45774 72.51956 36.98077 33.22457 45.25833 59.28694
#> [25] 98.41030 36.39350 69.02367 51.82203 68.45499 96.95839
#> [1] 48.96433 89.56191 63.90551 73.54613 99.35293 74.60017 25.81102 21.54059 98.78785 78.26632 45.56900 75.22186
#> [13] 44.45236 80.81733 87.45434 23.85018 62.25944 26.33234 63.73642 64.93282 79.85623 29.66782 33.67150 67.01610
#> [25] 74.98264 38.05653 29.91142 63.60954 26.37593 24.21256
#> [1] 1 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 2
Levels: 1 2 3
```

Nesse caso não é semanticamente correto, ainda que possa ser correto do ponto de vista da sintaxe, usar o `i` nesse contexto porque `i` não tem mais nomes. Vejamos:

```
for (i in df_1) print(names(i))
#> NULL
#> NULL
```

Ou seja, o código do loop 3 passa `NULL` como `x` para `pairwise.t.test` e ai parece que o loop não é rodado.

## Loop 4

Por fim no Loop 4 aparece a diferença de fazer o *subset* de um `data.frame` usando o `[` com e sem a vírgula (o espaço não faz diferença para o interpretador do [r](/questions/tagged/r)). 
Vejamos o que ocorre quando imprimimos um e outro caso:

```
for (i in vars) print(head(df_1[i]))
#>        x.1
#> 1 30.26077
#> 2 82.59508
#> 3 71.04249
#> 4 99.67011
#> 5 36.02907
#> 6 20.69992
#>        x.2
#> 1 48.96433
#> 2 89.56191
#> 3 63.90551
#> 4 73.54613
#> 5 99.35293
#> 6 74.60017
for (i in vars) print(head(df_1[, i]))
#> [1] 30.26077 82.59508 71.04249 99.67011 36.02907 20.69992
#> [1] 48.96433 89.56191 63.90551 73.54613 99.35293 74.60017
```

Enquanto `df_1[i]` mantém a forma de `data.frame` da saída, `df_1[, i]` retorna um vetor que perde sua característica de `data.frame`.

Isso justifica a mensagem de erro do `tapply` já que o `length` de um `data.frame` é seu número de colunas e não quantidade de registros (como no caso em que é passado um vetor). Comparam-se tamanhos de 1 (uma coluna de `df_1[i]`) com `n` (o tamanho de registros da coluna `df_1$y`) e o `tapply` "joga" o erro da pergunta.

Comment: Tomás, obrigado. Só uma dúvida adicional: como ficaria esse loop em uma lista? Exemplo de lista: `lista <- split(df_1, df_1$y)`

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem. Será que vale fazer uma nova pergunta explicando melhor?